# Publish a new version of a Chrome Extension to just testers (initially)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an unlisted extension published through the Chrome web store which is already being used. I have a new version which I would like to release just to testers initially, before a full roll out to everyone. Can this be done?

The same thing has been asked here but it was almost 9 years ago, and the answers disagree on whether it's possible or not:
[How to publish new version of Chrome Extension only to testers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098325/how-to-publish-new-version-of-chrome-extension-only-to-testers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, it can't be done for a published extension".

According to Chrome Web Store visibility descriptions, you must unpublish an extension before it can be published to trusted testers. Users who already have it installed will get updated to the new version.

In your case, you have to create a new extension with the new code, and a different name like "MyApp Beta" and publish it privately to the [list of trusted testers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-dashboard-distribution/#private-visibility-trusted-testers).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already know this, but you can [install a chrome extension manually](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/install-a-chrome-extension/).

1. Go to chrome://extensions/ and check the box for Developer mode in the top right.
2. Click "Load unpacked exention"
3. Select the folder where your unzipped extension resides in.

So, you can send a zip/rar to your testers, let them follow the procedure and test the extension. Might be that you have to give it another name so as to not conflict with your earlier eversion, or you could ask your testers to delete the existing extension to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I did know this, afraid it's not really what Im asking or a suitable solution for me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way is to pack a .crx file of the tester-only extension then link to it via some cloud-hosting service like Google Drive. There is no way to do this through the Web Store. You could release a different extension as a beta channel though.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly related to publishing a full extension, but ... you could use feature toggling to control the visibility of new functionality? So wrap the new functionality in toggle checks and only turn the feature on based on some criteria you can decide in a custom roll-out strategy. See [enter link description here](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash) for an open-source implementation of a feature toggle control system.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a developer account and want to publish it on the chrome web store privately to just testers this is what you have to do:

1. Go to the Pricing and Distribution page of the extension during the publishing process
2. Click "Private"
3. Go to your developer account settings, and in the "Management" section, you can add trusted tester accounts.

You can change the status to public whenever your extension is ready.

Comment: This wont work for me. I already have users who arn't testers. If I do this they will get the release, even if they arn't trusted testers. Also the extension will no longer visible to new users who arn't testers.